# RegEx number not surrounded by other numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to get a six digit number that is not surrounded by any other number, and is not in a sequence of numbers. This number can exist at the beginning of the string, anywhere in it, and at the end. It can also have commas and text in front of it, but most importantly distinct 6 digit blocks of numbers. I've pulled my hair out doing lookaheads and conditions and can't find a complete solution that solves all issues.

Sample data:

```
00019123211231731ORDER NO 761616 BR ADDRESS 123 A ST
ORDER NO. 760641 JOHN DOE
REF: ORDER #761625
OP212312165 ORDER NUMBER 759699 /REC/YR 123 A ST
766911
761223,761224,761225
```

Answer (score 5):

`(^|\D)(\d{6})(\D|$)`. You will find your needed 6 digit match in capturing group 2. *Notice that this solution is reliable only for one match. It won't find both numbers in `123456,567890` (Thank you Alan for pointing this out!). If multiple matches are needed a lookaround solution should be used.*

With look-arounds:

`(?<=^|\D)\d{6}(?=\D|$)`

or with look-arounds and the condition to be a valid number (i.e. the first digit is not 0):

`(?<=^|\D)[1-9]\d{5}(?=\D|$)`

Comment: This may not be 100% complete. He indicates he needs them to not be in a sequence of numbers. I'm a little unsure what he means by sequence in this case.

Comment: @Thomas I think he doesn't want 6 digit parts of sequences longer than 6. He'll probably add a comment if I'm wrong.

Comment: Most likely so, was just pondering over it. I found it odd he specified not surrounded by a number _AND_ not in a sequence of numbers. Perhaps it was just redundancy for emphasis, but I took it as possibly meaning two different things.

Comment: I don't want it to match 731223 in a sequence like 00012373122300182. I forgot to add the regex I already have: [1-9][0-9]{5}

Comment: This seems to be successful, at least partially. Still having issues with it catching numbers in sequences:
[1-9][0-9]{5}(?![\dA-Za-z])(?!<[\dA-Za-z])

I actually decided to READ for once

Comment: If all you meant by sequence was you don't want to match 6 digits in a group of 10 then exactly what Alin posted should work.

Comment: (?<=^|\D)[1-9][0-9]{5}(?=\D|$) final solution seems to work fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Rob `[0-9]` is the same thing as `\d`. What you final solution has changed is enforce that the first digit is not `0`. I'll add this version to the answer as well.

Comment: I'd use negative lookarounds for this: `(?<!\d)[1-9]\d{5}(?!\d)`  @Rob, your negative-lookaround solution was broken in two ways: (1) the lookbehind should have been at the beginning of the regex, and (2) the exclamation point is supposed to go *after* the angle bracket, i.e. `(?<!`.  `(?!<[\dA-Za-z])` is a negative **lookahead** for an angle bracket followed by a letter or digit.

Comment: @Alan Is there any advantage if you use negative lookarounds as opposed to negated classes? My hunch would say that there is not difference in this case.

Comment: @Alin: Lookarounds don't consume any characters.  Try your regex on that last line, with three numbers separated by commas.  The second `\D` consumes the comma following the number, leaving nothing for the *first* `\D` to match the next time around.

Comment: @Alan Are you referring to my first regex, the one that doesn't use lookarounds? I asked if there is any advantage in using negative lookarounds as oposed to positive ones with negated classes. If you look at my answer you will see that I use positive lookarounds for the second and third regex.

Comment: Oops!  Actually, I answered your question without referring back to your answer, and the question didn't say anything about positive lookarounds.  The advantage of using *negative* lookarounds is that it expresses your intent more concisely, e.g.: "not preceded by a digit" vs. "preceded by a digit or the beginning of the string".

Comment: @Alan You mean: vs. "preceded by something that is not a digit or not preceded by anything". I think they are pretty much equivalent, but this is subjective.

Comment: @Alin: Yeah, that was supposed to be "preceded by a *non-digit*..."

Answer (score 3):

You can use a **negative lookbehind** and **negative lookahead** to make sure there are no digits adjacent to the match:

```
(?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d)
```

This *only* matches the number, and not the adjacent characters.
Also, it works if the match is at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: Matching only the 6-digit number is useful when you can't use named capturing groups, such as when searching in Notepad++.

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you just as easily use this regex

```
[^0-9](\d{6})[^0-9]
```

It should match any 6 digit number, not padded by any other numbers.  Therefore not being in a sequence.

Comment: This would fail with the string `012345`.

Comment: Matches can't overlap, so you need a lookbehind and lookahead. Example: "zz123456,987654,234531xy" even though your regex only captures the digits the match is actually "z123456," and because matches can't overlap 987654 will be ignored and the next match will be ",234531x"

Comment: this matches other characters for example `,123456,`